# Property 'text' not found on object of type NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, text, textfield, nslayoutconstraint

I am using iOS 8.4. I received the following error: Property 'text' not found on object of type 'NSLayoutConstraint'.

Here is the section of code that it shows up in.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)seque sender: (id) sender {
    if (sender != self.savebutton) 
        return;

    if (self.textfield.text.length > 0) {
       self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
       self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textfield.text;
       self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}
```

I'm lost. Is this error saying that I should define "text"? Or is it saying something is wrong with the constraints of the text field?

Comment: Most likely you have associated the wrong object with your `textField` IBOutlet - It is one of the text field's constraints rater than the text field itself. Check in Interface Builder

Comment: I'll check that out. 
Thanks.